# Asymptotic distribution of a specific sample statistic

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

Consider a random independent sample of size $n$ from a distribution defined by the following probability density function$$f(x)=\frac{3}{4}\cdot\left(1-x^2\right)$$ when $-1<x<1$, zero otherwise.

I would like to find an asymptotic formula for the PDF of $$\frac{-\frac{n}{2}+\sum\frac{X_i^2}{1-X_i^2}}{2\sum\frac{X_i^2}{(1-X_i^2)^2}}$$ where $X_i$ are the sample values. Numerical exploration yields a double-exponential shape (see below), becoming more symmetrical as $n$ increases, and whose variance seems proportional to $n^{-1}$ (deriving the leading term of such a variance formula is my primary objective).
This is how the distribution looks like when $n=1000$ [image]

Answer (score 1):

By the SLLN we can see that

$$
\frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{X_k^2}{1-X_k^2}\to \frac1{2}\quad \text{a.s.}
$$

and that

$$
\frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{X_k^2}{(1-X_k^2)^2}\to +\infty \quad \text{ a.s. }
$$

Therefore

$$
\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{X_k^2}{1-X_k^2}-\frac{n}{2}}{2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{X_k^2}{(1-X_k^2)^2}}=\frac{\frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{X_k^2}{1-X_k^2}-\frac1{2}}{\frac2{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{X_k^2}{(1-X_k^2)^2}}\to 0\quad \text{ a.s. }
$$

Finally, as almost sure convergence imply convergence in distribution it means that the distribution of the statistic converges to the Dirac distribution around zero as the sample size increases.

Comment: I know this is my fault (not phrasing the question correctly - and I still don't know how to do that, perhaps you can help me to do that), but I need (at least) a formula for its variance, say V=3/(n*ln(n) ), and then its asymptotic shape, i.e. lim of the PDF of the RV/sqrt(V), if possible.

Comment: @Honza this is a completely different question. Open a new question about it and specify it correctly.

Comment: I hope that the new version of the question somehow clarifies my objectives; I acknowledge that Masacroso answered correctly the original version.